# Jquery mask on ASP.NET not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to apply the mask I got from http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ but the mask is just not working. here is my code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function ($) {
                $("#cnpjDate").mask("99/99/9999", { placeholder: "dd/mm/yyyy" });
                $("#date").mask("99/99/9999", { placeholder: "mm/dd/yyyy" });
                $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
                $("#tin").mask("99-9999999");
                $("#ssn").mask("999-99-9999");
            });

        </script>
</asp:Content>
```

My input field is like this

```
<input id="cnpjDate" type="text" /></td>
```

and it's inside a table, which is inside a View, inside a multiview inside a ContentTemplate which is inside am UpdatePanel.

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: do you see any error if you look in your browser's console and are you sure that the rendered input has the same id?

Comment: The browser doesn't show any errors. What would be the rendered input?

Comment: that would be when you run the project or publish it, you can see it in the devtools

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the masked-input-plugin is using the .on function in jQuery which isn't available in jQuery 1.4.2, you need to update your jQuery version or downgrade the masked-input-plugin.

Also make sure to run your jQuery function after the dom has loaded:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {});
```

Here is a working [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Mwzmpv)

Answer (score 0):

Since the update panel is getting loaded via ajax, the Jquery methods are not binding to the DOM elements. To resolve this bind the methods on a dom element that is higher up and not getting loaded via ajax.

Try this script:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">       
</asp:Content>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $('body').on('click','#cnpjDate',function(){
             $(this).mask("99/99/9999", { placeholder: "dd/mm/yyyy" });
        }); 
        $('body').on('click','#date',function(){
             $(this).mask("99/99/9999", { placeholder: "mm/dd/yyyy" });
        }); 
        $('body').on('click','#phone',function(){
             $(this).mask("(999) 999-9999");
        }); 
        $('body').on('click','#tin',function(){
             $(this).mask("99-9999999");
        }); 
        $('body').on('click','#ssn',function(){
             $(this).mask("999-99-9999");
        }); 
    });
</script>
```